# Moment of inertia of a solid sphere with a spherical cavity cut out of it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to solve the Following question. 
**Consider a sphere of radius R with a cavity of radius r cut out of it. The distance between sphere and cavity center is a such that  a < R-r. Find all the components of moment of inertia**

I have the following approach to solve this. The problem has spherical top symmetry so inertia tensor would have only diagonal elements with $I_{11} =I_{22} = I_{33} = (2/5)MR^2$. Now if we cut a spherical cavity out of it then the inertia tensor again have only diagonal elements, again because of symmetry argument, and have values $$I_{11} = I_{22} = I_{33} =I_{sp} - I_{cav} = (2/5)(M/R^3)[R^5 - r^5]$$
where Mass of the small sphere (cavity) is $M(r^3/R^3)$, based of uniform mass density argument.

Is my approach correct or I am missing something?

Best,

Fasi

Answer (score 1):

You’re assuming more symmetry than is present. The cavity is offset from the center along some axis. Call the axis $z$ and the direction of offset “up”.

Then the cavity reduces the moment about $z$, but it reduces the moment about $x$ and $y$ *more* as its further from those axes.

Comment: I am assuming three separate cases viz; In the first i place cavity's center on the x-axis and calculate $I_{11}$, Then simillarly on y- and z-axis for $I_{22}$ and $I_{33}$.

I have also tried calculating $I_{12}$ by using formula for inertia tensor but it vanished, both for sphere and cavity, because of the integral over phi.

Please guide if i am still on wrong track.

Comment: I doubt very much that’s the intended meaning of the question.

Comment: The cavity is in one place. It can’t be centered on three different axes.

Comment: Yes Smith, Thank you. i got it.